# Heatmap based on 3 variables

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap

I have this dataframe:

```
     var1 var2 value
1    A    X    0
2    B    X    1
3    C    X    1
4    A    Y    1
5    B    Y    0
6    C    Y    0
```

and I would like to plot var1 in the X-axis and var2 in the Y-axis, and plot the value as a red if it is a 1, and white if it is zero. In this case, kind of:

```
  A     B     C
X white red   red
Y red   white white
```

So far, I have tried with:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(var1, var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)  + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "red"))
```

but the plot is wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2, ~value,
    "A",    "X",    0,
    "B",    "X",    5,
    "C",    "X",    4,
    "A",    "Y",    1,
    "B",    "Y",    2,
    "C",    "Y",    0.5,
) 

df %>%
    ggplot(aes(var1, var2, fill = value)) +
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]